# How to boot Ubuntu automatically?

Tags: boot, startup, bios, grub-efi

I am using **Ubuntu GNOME 13.10**. I have made one backup image with **Clonezilla**. The backup includes 2 partitions — one is `/dev/sda1`, where is the EFI (only the EFI folder from `/boot/efi/EFI`), and the other is `/dev/sda2/`, where is my root directory with all other files (`/`). I have installed the OS through EFI.

Everything was fine — I could restore my backup without any problems. But I bought new hard disk drive, because of failure of the old one.

I installed the new hard disk and everything was fine again, except one thing. I am restoring the backup without any problems, but after the POST screen the OS is not booting — it opens the GRUB command-line interface every time!

I boot the OS with the following commands:

```
linux (hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd (hd0,gpt2)/initrd.img
boot
```

The OS boots, but on the screen I see this error: `The disk drive /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present`. Okay, I have found the solution for this — the OS boots in BIOS mode, not in EFI and I removed the EFI line in `/etc/fstab`. The error does not show on the screen anymore.

**But the GRUB command-line interface starts before the OS every time. And I need to load the kernel manually on every startup. How to make the OS start automatically?**

And how to make the OS to boot in EFI again (it is not mandatory, but I am searching for a solution)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file is broken. Maybe GRUB tries to boot your system partition by UUID, but your new partition have different UUID? You can check your partition UUID by running this in terminal:

```
sudo blkid
```

That UUID should also be in your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, so if it isn't there, it might be the problem. You can correct it manually or just update GRUB files:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If it doesn't help, you can try reinstalling GRUB:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

(where /dev/sdX is your system drive).

If you can't boot your system, you can use Live CD, of course, but you need to bind your /dev, /proc and /sys directories:

1. Download Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 ISO file.
2. Burn it on CD or pendrive (with UNetbootin).
3. Boot from that Live CD.
4. In terminal:

   Mount your system root drive, where /dev/sdXY is partition with your system, you can check it in GParted to be sure.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
   ```

   Bind some directories GRUB needs access to.

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```

   Change your root directory.

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

   Install GRUB (/dev/sdX is where GRUB will be installed, e.g. MBR sector of your system drive).

   ```
   grub-install /dev/sdX
   update-grub
   ```

   Return to your normal root directory and unmount all.

   ```
   exit

   sudo umount /mnt/dev
   sudo umount /mnt/proc
   sudo umount /mnt/sys
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```
5. Now reboot and your GRUB should work.